# Optimize R code for row operations on ternary data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization, rowsum

## Problem

I have this function that I need to make it go faster :)

```
if (length(vec) == 0) { # first case
  count = sum(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
    all(x == 0, na.rm = T)
  }))
} else if (length(vec) == 1) { # second case
  count = sum(df[, vec], na.rm = T)
} else {
  count = sum(apply(df[, vec], 1, function(x) { # third case
    all(x == 1) }), na.rm = T)
}
```

`df` is a `data.frame` with **only 1, 0 or NA values**. `vec` is a sub-vector of the `colnames(df)`.

- **First case**: count the rows thta after the NA's are removed, they have only 0's (or nothing - e.g. the row had only NA's - you count it too)
- **Second case**: count the 1's in the vector (1 column chosen only) after removing the NA's
- **Third case**: from the filtered data.frame get the number of rows that have all their values equal to 1.

## Question

Is there any way you think that can make this code run faster using `dplyr` or something else since it manipulates the data frame by row? For example, when I exchanged the easier one (2nd case) - `count = sum(df[, vec], na.rm = T)` with `dplyr`: `sum(df %>% select(vec), na.rm = T)` and did a benchmark, it was considerably worse (but ok I don't think 2nd case can get considerably faster with any method).

Any tips or tricks for 2st and 3rd cases are welcome!

## Benchmarking

A huge enough data.frame to play with: `df = matrix(data = sample(c(0,1,NA), size = 100000, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10000, ncol = 10)`.

- The **first case**:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark("prev" = {sum(apply(df, 1, function(x) {all(x == 0, na.rm = T)}))}, "new-long" = {sum((rowSums(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE) + rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df)))}, "new-short" = {sum(!rowSums(df != 0, na.rm = TRUE))}, replications = 1000, columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
```

**Results**:

```
       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2  new-long         1000   1.267    1.412     1.267        0
3 new-short         1000   0.897    1.000     0.897        0
1      prev         1000  11.857   13.219    11.859        0
```

- The **third case** (`vec = 1:5` for example):

```
rbenchmark::benchmark("prev" = {sum(apply(df[, vec], 1, function(x) { all(x == 1) }), na.rm = T)}, "new" = {sum(!rowSums(replace(df[, vec], is.na(df[, vec]), -999) != 1))}, replications = 1000, columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
```

**Results**:

```
test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2  new         1000   0.179    1.000     0.175    0.004
1 prev         1000   2.219   12.397     2.219    0.000
```

Overall, nice speedup using the `rowSums`! Use it too instead of `apply`!

Comment: You may need `rowSums` which would be vectorized.  Without a reproducible example, it is difficult for others to come up with a solution.  For the first case `sum(!rowSums(df != 0, na.rm = TRUE))`  The second case seems fine and the third case would be `sum(!rowSums(df[, vec] !=1, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @akrun thanks! The third case is wrong though (outputs a lot more rows) - I want to keep only the rows that have all values equal to 1 and add them to the row count...

Comment: Not able to reproduce with this example `df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1), col2 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2));sum(!rowSums(df!=1, na.rm = TRUE))#
[1] 2`

Comment: Maybe because the `df` has only 0, 1 and NA (I think)?

Comment: As I mentioned above, the post didn't show any reproducible example, so it is unclear

Comment: I know, I know :) Trying to make one!

Comment: Use: `df = data.frame(col1 = c(0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0), col2 = c(0,0, NA, 1, 1, 1))`. Then the 3rd case would be like this: `sum(apply(df, 1, function(x) { all(x == 1) }), na.rm = T)` (result: 1 row only) and yours: `sum(!rowSums(df != 1, na.rm = TRUE))` (results: 3 rows)

Comment: Sorry, try this `sum(!rowSums(replace(df, is.na(df), -999) != 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option to optimize the code with `rowSums` for the first and third case.  As there would be edge cases when the rows values are `NA`, one option is to replace those values with a value not in the dataset, create a logical matrix, use `rowSums` to convert it to a logical `vector` and get the `sum` of `TRUE` values

```
sum((rowSums(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE) + rowSums(is.na(df)) == ncol(df)))
```

Or

```
sum(!rowSums(df != 0, na.rm = TRUE))
sum(!rowSums(replace(df[, vec], is.na(df[, vec]), -999) != 1))
```

Comment: The `na.rm` is needed in the first? (since you replace all NA's with -999)

Comment: @John  No, it is not needed, I forgot to remove it.  thanks

Comment: @John Please let me know if it improved the efficiency

Comment: Ok, testing it a little bit myself and benchmarking it and accepting it afterwards! Thanks!

Comment: First is not correct anymore! But we can keep the `sum(!rowSums(df != 0, na.rm = TRUE))` I guess...

Comment: @John Based on your example, I get `sum(!rowSums(replace(df, is.na(df), -999) != 0))#[1]` which is the number of all 0's in a row.  Did you meant the logic to be without the `NA` or with the NA?

Comment: So, what the first case does is this: take a row, remove the NA's => if only zeros (0's) remain count that row. Even if there are no elements (all rows was NA's) count that row.

Comment: @John that means a row with all `NA` is also counted, right?

Comment: Yes that is true!

Comment: The solution for the first case with only one use of `rowSums` is a little bit faster than the one with two uses.

Comment: @John But, I guess it is still faster than the `apply`, right?

Comment: Updated answer with benchmark and overall results. Thanks!